# Displaying ASP.NET Chart controls in ASP.NET MVC site with virtual path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts, asp.net-charts

I have a simple project that combines ASP.NET MVC with ASP.NET Charts control. Code is super simple and works IF I do not specify any "Virtual Path" when I run it in VS 2008. I followed Mike Ceranski post on his blog here: http://www.codecapers.com/post/Build-a-Dashboard-With-Microsoft-Chart-Controls.aspx

But, if I put a virtual path (in the "Web" tab in project properties), it will fail and produce this error: Failed to map the path '/ChartImg.axd'. So it seems that it is still looking to call ChartImg.axd in the root directory instead of inside the virtual path.

So, my question is - how do I get it to go to the virtual path instead?

I have also done where the controller's action just return the image filestream - which I don't want - since eventually I want to be able to make the chart clickable instead of just a plain image.

Here is my web.config settings related to ASP.NET Chart:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;URL=/App_Data/MicrosoftChartControls/"/>
</appSettings>

<httpHandlers>
    ...
    <add verb="*" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Code for the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
    ViewData["Chart"] = BindChartData();
    return View();
}

private Chart BindChartData() {
    Chart chart = new Chart();
    chart.Width = 150;
    chart.Height = 300;
    chart.Attributes.Add("align", "left");            

    chart.Titles.Add("MY CHART");  
    chart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());

    chart.Series.Add(new Series());
    chart.Legends.Add(new Legend("MY CHART"));
    chart.Legends[0].TableStyle = LegendTableStyle.Auto;
    chart.Legends[0].Docking = Docking.Bottom;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        string x = ChartTest.Models.Utility.RandomText();
        decimal y = ChartTest.Models.Utility.RandomNumber(1, 100);
        int ptIdx = chart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x, y);
        DataPoint pt = chart.Series[0].Points[ptIdx];
        pt.LegendText = "#VALX: #VALY";
    }

    chart.Series[0].Legend = "MY CHART";
    return chart;
}
```

Code for the aspx:

```
<%         
    supportChart.Controls.Add(ViewData["Chart"] as Chart);        
%>
<asp:Panel ID="supportChart" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a path to be ignored, you have to add the specific path to the IgnoreRoute.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("VirtualPath/{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

I was also able to get it to work in my particular case using:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{controller}/{action}/{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

Comment: The problem is NOT that it is mapped to the virtual path and then ignore it by route to solve it. The problem is that it is NOT mapped to my virtual directory. So, it is mapped to the default axd in root instead of mapped to my virtual dir.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no routing expert, but you might need something like this in your global.asax:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

Comment: Already did that - and like I mentioned, if no virtual path - it works as it should. But adding virtual path breaks it.